# Chromium doesn't start under docker without `xhost +local:`

Tags: docker, chrome, xauth

```
$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
```

`xterm` works:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --network host \
  --volume ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:ro \
  --env DISPLAY \
  alpine:3.19 sh -euxc 'apk add xterm; exec xterm'
```

`chromium` opens a window and seems to receive keystokes, but the window is empty ([output](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/4ea76b753b9700b09857a671c2d0349b)):

```
$ docker run --rm -it --network host \
  --volume ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:ro \
  --env DISPLAY \
  alpine:3.19 sh -euxc 'apk add chromium; exec chromium --no-sandbox'
```

If I allow local connections with `xhost` it works:

```
$ xhost +local:

$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
LOCAL:

$ docker run --rm -it --network host \
  --volume ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:ro \
  --env DISPLAY \
  alpine:3.19 sh -euxc 'apk add chromium; exec chromium --no-sandbox'

$ xhost -local:
```

One could speculate here that it starts non-root processes which don't have access to `/root/.Xauthority`, and that's why it fails. Then under which user? So that I could provide `.Xauthority` to all interested parties. How do I debug this? How do I make it work?

Comment: Chromium very much dislikes running as root. Usually, you even have to pass a command line option to make it do that at all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but it probably makes more sense to run `chromium` under non-root:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --network host \
  --volume ~/.Xauthority:/.Xauthority:ro \
  --env DISPLAY \
  alpine:3.19 \
  sh -euxc 'apk add chromium shadow
            useradd -m a
            cp .Xauthority /home/a
            chown a: /home/a/.Xauthority
            exec su - a -c "DISPLAY=\"$DISPLAY\" exec chromium --no-sandbox --no-first-run"'
```

Or better yet (I'm assuming you're running under PID 1000):

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.19
RUN apk add chromium shadow && useradd -m a
```

```
$ docker run --rm -it --network host \
  --volume ~/.Xauthority:/home/a/.Xauthority:ro \
  --env DISPLAY \
  -u 1000 \
  i chromium --no-sandbox --no-first-run
```

Or using a [`chromium` seccomp profile](https://github.com/jessfraz/dotfiles/blob/master/etc/docker/seccomp/chrome.json) (created in 2016), which let's us avoid `--no-sandbox`:

```
$ curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jessfraz/dotfiles/master/etc/docker/seccomp/chrome.json
$ docker run --rm -it --network host \
  --volume ~/.Xauthority:/home/a/.Xauthority:ro \
  --env DISPLAY \
  -u 1000 \
  --security-opt seccomp=chrome.json \
  i chromium --no-first-run
```

The seccomp profile was taken from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59087200/google-chrome-failed-to-move-to-new-namespace/64460373#64460373) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662388/running-headless-chrome-puppeteer-with-no-sandbox/53975412#53975412), and here's the [description](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/how-to-use-new-docker-seccomp-profiles/) of how it was created.